# Public Facing Site - Bcrypt Password validation slow response in web application with increased concurrent users

Tags: spring, performance, validation, authentication, bcrypt

We are using bcrypt algorithm to validate users and what we've noticed is that as the number of concurrent users increases, the time taken to run the bcrypt algorithm increases exponentially. Since our application is a public facing site, the delay for user login is unacceptable. The login performance for one user is around 2.5 seconds (with only a single active user) and with 20 concurrent users it goes up to 30 seconds. (bcrypt response time per user)

Few more details:
a. Web application is hosted on AWS EC2 Instance.
b. Spring provided bcrypt library is being used to do password validation.

I have seen other articles in stackoverflow mentioning that bcrypt is specifically designed to be slow to make it more robust. However, how do web applications handle security otherwise? What is the next best fall back option?

Comment: Why does it even take 2.5s. We use Crypt also and notice no such thing (Spring Security 4.0.4). So might be your implementation or how your AWS is setup.

Comment: You mean bcrypt? We use Spring Security 3.2.7, I'll check if upgrading to a higher version (4.0.4) will solve the issue.